# Azure VPN using RADIUS to solve local admin requirements

Tags: vpn, azure, radius, point-to-site-vpn

Now that Azure point to site VPN can be authenticated via [RADIUS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/point-to-site-vpn-client-configuration-radius), would using RADIUS instead of certificates change the need for local admin privilege?

I have clients that connect to Azure via point to site VPN without local admin rights.  The only way I was able to make it work was manually installing the VPN in Windows 7 and installing the certificates with admin rights.  Problem is they don't have internet access on their local machine when connected to the Azure VPN as standard users.

Site to site VPN is not an option as per the clients IT group for security reasons.

I'd be willing to setup a RADIUS and AD server on the clients Azure v-net if this could be a possible workaround.